# Program is not entering into FOR loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I don't know why, but the program is not entering into the FOR loop.
I am completely new to programming so Please avoid any errors if there.
Help much appreciated.

This question is from one of the coding websites::

> You are given a list of N people who are attending ACM-ICPC World Finals. Each of them are either well versed in a topic or they are not. Find out the maximum number of topics a 2-people team can know. And also find out how many teams can know that maximum number of topics?
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains two integers N and M separated by a single space, where N represents the number of people, and M represents the number of topics. N lines follow.
>   Each line contains a binary string of length M. In this string, 1 indicates that the ith person knows a particular topic, and 0 indicates that the ith person does not know the topic.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> On the first line, print the maximum number of topics a 2-people team can know. 
>   On the second line, print the number of teams that can know the maximum number of topics.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> ```
> 2 ≤ N ≤ 500 
>
> 1 ≤ M ≤ 500
> ```
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4 5
> 10101
> 11100
> 11010
> 00101
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 5
> 2
> ```

Here is my code ::

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N,M;
    cin>>N>>M;

    if(N>=2 && N<=500 && M>=1 && M<=500){
        int x= (N*(N-1))/2;
        int i,j,k;
        int Topic[x];
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
            Topic[i]=0;
        }
        int y= N*M;
        int a;
        char Array[y];
        while(N--){
            for(i=0;i<M;i++){   
                cin>>Array[a];
                a++;
            }  
          }
        int count;
        int d=0;
        int l=N-1;

        // This FOR LOOP ..

        **for(int p=0;p<l;p++){             
            for(int q=p+1;q<N;q++){
                count=0;
                for(k=0;k<M;k++){
                    int temp=k+(q*M);
                    int temp1=k+(p*M);
                    if(Array[temp]+Array[temp1]!=0){
                        count+=1;
                    }
                }
                Topic[d]=count;
                d++;
            }
        }**
        int max=Topic[0];
        int counter=0;
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
            if(max>Topic[i]){
                 max=Topic[i];  
                 counter=1;
            }
            else if(Topic[i+1]=Topic[i]){
                counter+=1;
            }
         }

     cout<<max<<endl;
     cout<<counter;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out N or l just before the loop to see if they are the problem?

Comment: You don't initialize `a` when you read into the array

Comment: learn do debug: set breakpoints (or write outputs) at certain points in your code. check your variables at those locations and try to follow the program logic manually. eliminate code until it works. put code back and pinpoint where you get unexpected results.

Comment: I tried to print other things instead of N or I ..

Comment: Yes, p was infact -1 when initialized. Thank you everyone for your help !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a loop that counts `N` down to `0`:

```
while (N--) {
  // ...
}
```

Then you set `l` to `N - 1`, which is to say `-1`:

```
int l = N - 1;
```

Then your `for` loop wants to run while `p < l`. `p` is initially `0`, `l` is initially `-1`, so the loop never runs:

```
for ( int p = 0; p < l; p++ ) {
  // ...
}
```